# Did Black, my colleague, cheat in our Lichess game?

Tags: engines, cheating

I recently played against a colleague of mine, who claimed to have a chess.com elo of about 1000. I am about 1700 on Lichess. We played 3 matches, where he won two. In these matches I got completely crippled, especially in this one. He says he can not calculate. He said he does not know what the "Queenside" (Damenflügel) is.

Still, we played Sicilian theory until move 6 or 7 (he also knows his Scotch really well). He never needed more time than 30 seconds of thinking.
The engine analyses says he made no mistake, nor a blunder, and only a few inaccuracies.

I would like to hear your thoughts on if he cheated or not. Here is our [Lichess game](https://lichess.org/4Ff4TZOs/white#11) for you to look over.

Comment: That was a pretty impressive game and definitely one above what a normal 1000 would play. But you made it easy on several occasions, so his play is not as impressive as what stockfish would pull off on you if you were to have instead played against your phone.

Comment: fwiw stockfish says the game is pretty equal up to move 24.

Comment: He may have an old rating of 1000, but this game was played more like he was a 2000.  Unless he feels that you've wronged him, I'd give him the benefit of the doubt and say that he wasn't cheating.  BTW, I'm rated as a master, which doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I suspect someone who knows some opening theory has a true rating above 1000.

Comment: Was the game played in person? If not, why do you not have a game in person to figure out what his true playing level is?

Comment: No, we cannot have a game in Person.